# simple enqueue action, not so simple

Tags: java

In my application is an exe class in a Java LinkedList queue data structure.

For some reason enqueue can't deal with the Student type. Everything seems fine except that I get this error:

```
The method enqueue(String) in the type LinkedQueue<String> is not 
applicable for the arguments (Student)
```

Here's the code. I've tried re-arranging things, but I'm really at a loss, I can't change the Queue class because its supposed to be generic.

```
String result;
LinkedQueue<String> queue = new LinkedQueue<String>();
Student []studentGroup = {
    new Student(new String("data")),
    new Student(new String("data")),
    new Student(new String("data")),
    new Student(new String("data")),
    new Student(new String("data"))};

for (int k = 0; k<studentGroup.length; k++ ) {
    queue.enqueue(studentGroup[k]);
}


}
}
```

Edit: was in the middle of editing it mate, but thanks. And yes its missing a main method and class name which is intentional since alot of people a googling for this code for an assignment.

So, I'm dubious about setting LinkedQueue as , because I'll have to do a dequeue and some other stuff and don't want to instantiate more than I have to.

But yea, I've been wracking my head over something so obvious, but then I've been awake for 34 hours. Thanks for pointing it out guys, it's much appreciated.

Comment: The code is not complete. Also please format the code appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

Your `LinkedQueue` has the generic type `String` but should have `Student` (if it's supposed to contain only `Student` objects (and specifications thereof)):

```
LinkedQueue<Student> queue = new LinkedQueue<Student>();
```

You might find the *"[Motivations for generics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Motivation_for_generics)"* on WikiPedia interesting. Lots of other resources on generics are available, too.

---

Also, why `new Student(new String("data")),`? `new Student("data"),` will be sufficient (and more readable) if the strings are *not* required to be different instances.

Comment: Is not the same. String s1 = "data"; String s2 = "data"; String s3 = new String("data"); Object s1 == s2 -> true but s1 == s3 > false

Comment: @Vash Oh, yes I guess that the "same" is not quite right. I will revise my text. However, in this specific case (if OP has posted "real" code) I find it hard to believe that the strings *must* be different instances.

Comment: It should work either way, I'd left it the way it is atm because I was tinkering with an idea and forget to change it back. This should be fine too                                                  new Student("A12345");

Comment: I only was referring to that "same". I also believe that this case do not need creation of new objects.

Answer (score 1):

By saying `LinkedQueue<String>` you are asking the compiler to check that all the elements in the list are of String type. You probably meant `LinkedQueue<Student>`.
If you want it to accept both (BAD idea), you can do `LinkedQueue<Object>`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add an object of type Student to a queue of Strings.
You should have:

```
LinkedQueue<Student> queue = new LinkedQueue<Student>();
```